# Send data of one website to multiple views?

Tags: google-analytics

Need help setting up Google Analytics tracking code; where data of the website is pushed into two views (blog and admin) separately.

I'll be adding tracking code to both Admin and Blog pages. The situation is like this.

**Website:** http://example.com/blog 
**Admin:** http://example.com/admin

Blog data goes the "Blog" view only and data related to the Admin-Panel goes to "admin" view. This all has to be done **Without using Filters**.

```js
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-X', 'example.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Without filters, but within same property?

Comment: Yes. So, I got one property with two views. I'm trying to push certain pages to certain views using the tracking code.

Comment: AFAIK that's not possible. You collect your data using the property code, and you can create different views by using filters. This is how filters work: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162?hl=en There are some other view-level settings, to customize your view, like channel and content grouping, but actual filtering is done by filters.

Comment: Thanks for your response. With filters, the process would be too complicated and messy. I have around 100 pages of the main webssite http://example.com and 20+ for admin only. It means, I'd have to manually include/exclude the pages from filter?

Comment: I thought, It would be much easier, if I could simply pass-on the unique view name inside the analytics tracking code, to track certain pages.

Comment: You can use patterns and regular expression in your filters, which can significantly reduce the number of necessary filters. You can also create a custom dimension to sort the pages during the data collection, and create only two filters based on the custome dimension value. I thought you didn't have user right to create filters, as a reason for not using them.

Comment: "custom dimension to sort the pages during the data collection,"

Awesome! That seems a good idea. Thanks for the help.